# Diffeomorphism between plane and cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The cylinder is given by $C=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2=1\}$. I want to prove that $C$ iis diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2-{(0,0)}$.

I have come up with a possible function, but I've been unable to prove it is surjective. The function I defined is

$$f(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},xy\right)$$.

By definition of $f=(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ is clear that $f_1^2+f_2^2=1$. The function is also injective because if $f(x,y)=f(w,z)$ then
$$
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{w}{\sqrt{w^2+z^2}} \\ 
\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{z}{\sqrt{w^2+z^2}}\\
xy=wz
$$

The product of the first two imply $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{wz}{w^2+z^2}$, since $xy=wz$ both denominators are the same, then applying this two the first two equation follows $x=w,y=z$.

Surjectivity is, as I said before, a problem. To find coordinates for $(a,b,c)$ I need to set $c=xy$, which doesn't seem to have enough freedom to allow me vary $x$ and $y$ as much as I would like to generate all the possible $a,b$.

On the differentiability, each component function is a composition of continuous differentiable functions in $\mathbb{R}-\{(0,0)\}$, so $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: The function is not injective. Any point $(0,y)$ with $y\neq0$ is mapped to $(0,1,0)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: any point in the plane minus the origin may be written uniquely in polar form using an angle and a radius. Furthermore, any point on your cylinder may be written uniquely using an angle and a z coordinate.

Comment: Thank you Another problem I counter: That function has only two variables, wouldn't then have a non-square jacobian matrix? I'm not sure if I can apply the inverse function theorem there.